# Telerik Cover Flow bubbling events from user control

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik, coverflow

I have a telrik coverflow, and the tiles in are of type InfoPageView, a user control. I have a button inside the InfoPageView user control from which i want to trigger an event at the parent.
I tried implementing the solution in this post: 
[Expose a Click event of a button inside a UserControl in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594363/expose-a-click-event-of-a-button-inside-a-usercontrol-in-silverlight) but i cant get the childs event in the parent class. Is there an alternate way to do this?

```
<telerikNavigation:RadCoverFlow x:Name="CoverFlow" Grid.Row="0" OffsetY="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Covers}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                DistanceBetweenItems="75" DistanceFromSelectedItem="25"  IsReflectionEnabled="False" ItemScale="0.5"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="785" Height="486">
                <telerikNavigation:RadCoverFlow.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:InfoPageView Name="Custinfopage" Width="390" Height="390" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikNavigation:RadCoverFlow.ItemTemplate>
            </telerikNavigation:RadCoverFlow>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Parent' do you want to 'trigger an event' in the RadCoverFlow control, or do you mean in InfoPageView? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I want to catch an event in RadCoverflow control / or the view that hosts the RadCoverflow [parent], the problem is that it is being generated by a button in InfoPageView.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on having the event bubble up from your inner view, you will need to rely upon routed events. The button will mark the LeftMouseButtonDown event as handled, which means you cant just use a straight forward event handler. What you can do though, is set up a listener for handled events.

You will need to verify that the event originated from the button you want, perhaps using a Tag on that button will suffice.

```
public MyOuterPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MyMouseLeftButtonDownEventHandler), true);
}

void MyMouseLeftButtonDownEventHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var button = e.OriginalSource as Button;
    if (button.Tag == "MyButton")
    {
        // do something with the event here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to catch the InfoPage usercontrol on my main page through the codebehind .cs file. So i injected the event in xaml:

```
<local:InfoPageView Name="Custinfopage" Width="390" Height="390" OnButtonClick="Button_click_event" />
```

In the main .CS file:

```
void Button_click_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        // Code
}
```

In the UserControl:

```
public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> OnButtonClick;

    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                if (OnButtonClick!= null){
                        OnButtonClick(sender, e);
                }

            }
```